# How can I reset a variable count in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating rows in a table using ng-repeat. I need to add variables to them self to get a running total. However, once that variable is larger than 25 I need to reset it back to 0. Here is my current code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="payoutqueue in payoutqueues" ng-init="payoutqueue.totalValue = +payoutqueues[$index-1].totalValue + +payoutqueue.balance_plain">
    <td align="left">{{$index}}</div></td>
    <td align="right"><div>{{payoutqueue.address}}</div></td>
    <td align="right"><div>{{payoutqueue.balance}}</div></td>
</tr>
```

I want to add a div behind `<div>{{payoutqueue.balance}}</div>` like this:

```
<div>{{payoutqueue.balance}}</div><div ng-if="payoutqueue.totalValue > 25">END</div>
```

and I only want `<div ng-if="payoutqueue.totalValue > 25">END</div>` to show up once `payoutqueue.totalValue` is greater than 25. I got this to work using `ng-if`, however, once I show `<div ng-if="payoutqueue.totalValue > 25">END</div>` I also need to reset `payoutqueue.totalValue=0` so I can start adding the loop again.

I tried doing this with help from another answer doing this: `<div ng-if="payoutqueue.totalValue > 25">END{{payoutqueue.balance=0;""}}</div>` however this didn't work.

To sum it up, I want to add a `<div>` after every time a variable added to itself is greater than 25. After the variable is greater than 25 I need to reset it to 0 and start adding to it again.

Here is what I am looking for if I were to do this in PHP:

```
<?php
$totalValue=0;
foreach($payoutqueues as $payoutqueue){
    $totalValue=$totalValue+payoutqueue['balance_plain'];
    echo $totalValue;
    if($totalValue > 25){
        $totalValue=0;
    }
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**
So I have not really found a solution that works well for me, so I just decided to do the math on the server side and add an extra element to my JSON file. Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have not really found a solution that works well for me, so I just decided to do the math on the server side and add an extra element to my JSON file. Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

Hello try using the following code

```
<tr ng-repeat="payoutqueue in payoutqueues" ng-init="checkTotalValue(payoutqueue)">
    <td align="left">{{$index}}</div></td>
    <td align="right"><div>{{payoutqueue.address}}</div></td>
    <td align="right">
        <div>{{payoutqueue.balance}}</div>
        <div ng-if="payoutqueue.totalValue > 25">
            END
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.totalValue = 0;
$scope.checkTotalValue = function(payoutqueue){
     $scope.totalValue = $scope.totalValue + payoutqueue.balance_plain;
     payoutqueue.totalValue = $scope.totalValue;
     if($scope.totalValue > 25)
     {
         $scope.totalValue = 0;
     }
}
```

This will work.
Following is the jsfiddle for the same:
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ashu12318/n9hv3uwn/3/)

Comment: Side note, it does properly reset the variable to 0; however, as it continues to loop, it no longer adds to itself again.

Comment: This is not adding to itself because you are using payoutqueue.totalValue which changes in each iteration, totalValue is a property of an element of the array payoutqueues which changes every iteration. Instead of using payoutqueue.totalValue try using a variable $scope.totalValue.

Comment: Your is not working because it might be possible that payoutqueue.totalValue never increases and hence never satisfying the condition

Comment: It is increasing, I am outputting it just to make sure. If I never try to set it to 0 it continues to add. I understand what you are saying, but I have no idea how I can get the loop to work and add to itself. Do you have an example of how to make that work?

Comment: Yes I did, but that doesn't show how I can increment that value by adding another value to it dynamically. If you look at my example you will see that I need to add a value to a variable, then once that variable is equal to 25, I need to set it back to 0 and start adding value back to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps do something hack-ish like:

```
<div ng-if="payoutqueue.totalValue > 25 && !(payoutqueue.balance = 0)">END</div>
```

But really you should move the logic into the controller, for example you could build a dictionary with the totals and access it via $index